# How should I repair this cracked front lip?

Tags: repair

[image]The lip underneath my front bumper is hanging, it seems to be because it's cracked on one of the ends as you can see in the picture.

will driving further cause it to get worse and so should I move it asap?

How should I repair it?  do i just put some superglue inbetween the crack or do I need to weld the plastic?

If I were to take this to a garage how long is the job?

Comment: Has the area around the screw just failed or did you hit a kerb? You probably need to reinforce the material, so glue, washers and possibly a longer screw would be a temporary solution... Replace would be the best...

Comment: @SolarMike I do apologise I have added a pic.

Comment: @JamesWilson Glue is difficult for low energy plastics like HDPE.  I picked up a plastic welder from HF to work on my front bumper and had pretty good success.  The Audi S Line is a little low and catches on curbs.  My bad.  Bumper is Polypropylene.  I ended up using 1/4" poly pro drip line cut into quarters and welded the flanges back on and patching a tear under the bottom lip.  Looks good and is strong.  I welded steel and aluminum for 6 years in a fab shop so it didn't take too long to figure it out.  Used the tacking nozzle to do all the welding. Tip - don't overheat and burn the paint.